# Wordpress - Migrate Theme In New Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migrate

I wondering how to migrate custom theme from another wordpress to another without copying the whole wordpress...

I already tried copy the folder theme to new wordpress, but it has a lot of problem, because in the new wordpress, there is no Page as in origin wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Create some pages and see if it works.

Some themes uses plugins also, you must copy them too.

By the way, there's a dedicated stackexchange site for wordpress : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can never expect the 100% same experience on another install since there may not be the same plugins, pages, images, server settings and so on and so on. You can not even be sure your theme work on the new wordpress if the WP version is diffrent from the one you made the theme on.